# Android: How to set first day of week in DateRangePicker?

Tags: android

**How to set first day of week to monday or saturday ?**

I can't find method or variable to change it. Like picture example below, first day of week is monday. Thanks in advance.

[image]

link github DateRangePicker https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker

Thanks for the answer. I finally figure it out. You need to initialize Locale and Timezone to change first day of week. Not calendar that you have to change. Don't need to break the library code too.

```
new CalendarPickerView.init(date1, date1, TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.UK, new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, YYYY", Locale.getDefault())) //
                        .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
                        .withSelectedDates(listDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first day of week is determined by your locale. 
Set it to something like `English (UK)` or `German` and you will have Monday as first day of week.

Then if it dosen't work you can change by code, like :

```
datePickerDialog.setFirstDayOfWeek(int weekStart);
```

If you want monday `weekStart = 2`

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Unfortunately DateRangePicker don't use DatePickerDialog.

Comment: But did you change your locale?

Comment: I did, but it's still not changed.

Comment: Which is the first day now ?

Comment: Can you update the solution? I fix this for the future gj

Comment: Could you accept the answer that is correct. Just for check it

Comment: I understood that was another question. I hope it help you!

Answer (score 1):

As per you using the DateRangePicker library :

For Example:

Use this code in your project.

```
    // create a calendar
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

   // set first day of the week as something else
     cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
```

or it will not run then required for you to change in library code with create method and put above code then used it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at that repository. The library creates days from 0 to 7 in a loop and gets days. See [this](https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker/blob/d66da2764ae258e1cf824a5978ca0a6ba3e16bb9/rangedatepicker/src/main/java/com/savvi/rangedatepicker/MonthView.java#L63).

The calendar here in use is created in `init` method in `CalendarPickerView`. Look at [CalendarPickerView](https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker/blob/master/rangedatepicker/src/main/java/com/savvi/rangedatepicker/CalendarPickerView.java#L205).

`today = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone, locale);`

I think if you change first day of week of calendar or default locale/timezone, you can do what you want.